# Confidence or prediction limits for significant difference between forecast and observation?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, forecasting, prediction-interval

My task is to to forecast business data without advertising and compare the real observations (with advertising effect) to the forecasted values in order to measure the effect of advertising.

I am confused as to whether I should use the confidence limits of the predicted values or the prediction limits to calculate significant difference?

I think I should perform a hypothesis test. My null hypothesis would be: there is no effect, the real observations will lie within the interval.

Answer (score 3):

You want a prediction interval which takes account of the variance of the observations. A confidence interval is normally for some parameter such as a mean. There is almost no use for a confidence interval in forecasting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Professor Hyndman. Do you know which ones are produced by the x12 package in R? The documentation says '
forecast_conf - probability for the conﬁdence interval of forecasts' but 'forecast - point forecasts with prediction intervals'

Comment: I don't know...